# convert a string holding byte array values to byte array

Tags: java

I'm reading messages from a TCP connection. The sender is sending a byte array but the `BufferedReader` reads it as a string. How can I convert the message to a byte array so I can then convert it to the actual message?

Say I want to send "hello". I use

```
String message = "hello"
byte[] byteData = message.getBytes();
```

I then send the message.
It's received as a string of, say, `0Bf3f3`.
I need to convert it back to "hello".

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.String` provides a constructor which takes an array of bytes. However, you need to keep in mind that the charset can be different at the receiver and sender side. For more details, see [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to convert a byte array back to a String:

```
String message = "hello";
byte[] byteData = message.getBytes();
String retMessage = new String(byteData); // <===
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers, they are flagged by the system as Low Quality Post and require admin validation

Comment: thanks but what if String is B@323j and I need the string to convert it to hello

Comment: Where are you getting "B@323j" from?

Answer (score 0):

Use buffered input stream for byte data.